# Canvas LineTo not working IOS / IPAD

Tags: javascript, ios, html, canvas

Hey there i have drawn a simple dot using canvas

```
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
 ctx.beginPath();
        //ctx.moveTo(last_mouse.x, last_mouse.y);
ctx.lineTo(120, 40);
```

But it does not show dot on IOS is only shows on Android / Windows

Comment: it doesn't show do on iOS but it shows on Android/iOS ???? please correct your question.

Comment: it does not show dot on IOS IPAD

Comment: @HelderSepu Chrome in all platforms

Answer (score 0):

Your code did not draw anything for me, on any browser...

I added a proper moveTo and a stroke at the end, here is the sample:

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';

  // Draw a Blue dot on the middle of the canvas
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 50;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  ctx.stroke();

  // Draw a diagonal Red line on the canvas
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width - 20, canvas.height - 20);
  ctx.stroke();
</script>
```